# I am trying to create a simple program to calculate percentage change, but I am having issues with printing the answer

Tags: python, int, typeerror

I am just starting out on python and i have very little previous experience with coding.

I have created a simple program to calculate percentage change, but with the line to print I am trying something slightly more complicated.

My current code is below:

```
num1 = float(input("what is the original number?"))

modi = float(input("How much do you want to increase it by?(please use 0.83/1.56 types rather than percentages)"))

ans = num1 * modi

print(ans,"is",modi,"times"if modi > 1 ("greater than")else "less than",num1)
```

The calculation works fine, but whenever i integrate the more advanced version of the print line it comes up with the error:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

I don't see anything wrong, can you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly use the `if` expression. Should be `"greater than" if modi > 1 else "less than"`. In general, the syntax of the expression is: `true_value if condition else false_value`. As written in your code snippet, Python interprets `1 ("greater than")` as an attempt to call function `1()` with the parameter `"greater than"`, thus the complaint about `1` being not callable.